# Waiting for dynamically generated Firebase list observables to finish

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to wait for several dynamically generated observables to finish so I can iterate through Firebase lists. I've tried with both forkJoin and zip but the last line doesn't log anything.

```
this.db.list<ChatByUser>(`chats_by_user/${this.userService.user.id}`).valueChanges().first().subscribe(chatsByUser => {
    const obsArray: Observable<Chat>[] = [];

    chatsByUser.forEach(chatByUser => {
        obsArray.push(this.db.object<Chat>(`chats/${chatByUser.chatId}`).valueChanges());
    });

    Observable.zip(obsArray).first().subscribe(chats => console.log(chats));
});
```

I don't know if it has something to do with it, but I'm using rxjs 6 with rxjs-compat and importing the operators like this:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";
```

Comment: You're subscribing to `valueChanges()` that emits only when a value changes. `zip` requires all source Observables to emit the same number of items so if any of the source Observables doesn't emit anything then `zip` won't emit anything either.

Comment: Subscribing to the dynamically generated observables inside the iterator returned values. If it can't be done with zip or forkJoin how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to consume the observables before adding them to the array. So adding the `first()` method to `valueChanges()` did the trick.